# How to get top 5 token holders?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, balances

I want to keep a track of top 5 token holders inside the contract in terms of their token balances, is there any efficient way to do that in solidity?

Comment: You can just keep an array with the top five in it, in sorted order. When someone's balance increases, see if it's better than the #5 slot. If so, find the right place to insert it and move the others down.

Comment: That's fine if balances only increase, but won't work when balances decrease.  If one of the top 5 transfers, say, their entire balance - not to another address, but to many addresses - who do you add to the top 5?

Answer (score 1):

You could store data in a heap which would approximately double your storage requirements (or less if you're willing to do some extra computation for indirection) for balances but gives you `O(log n)` changes and you can get the top 5 holders in `O(log n)`. You might also consider a sorted list for the entirety of the list (not just the top 5); insertions/deletions are `O(log n)` and lookups are `O(1)`. In all cases here, `n` is the number of token holders.

Comment: can u direct me to implementation of it?